# Textbox control like "TO" field in outlook

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I'm looking for a Textbox control that works similar to the email recipient textboxes in Outlook (the To, Cc and Bcc inputs). It shall have below characteristics.

- Allow user text inputs with auto complete based on history
- Word/Phrase identification, separation, underlining (like links)
- Keep a list of objects represented by these words/phrases
- Once click on a work/phrase fire an event to show the corresponding object related to that entry.

If nothing is out there, I may look to develop one by my own. Any help to direct me either on existing controls or how to do it, is highly appreciated.

Tks,
- Eranga

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of products out there but i'd approach this problem by having a look at the code in the richtextbox [WPF Extended toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) (you can nuget it but i'd download the code)

In there is a formatter which will allow you to markup flowdocuments in the rtb. if each address is stored as a run in the rtb you have your list of separate items which you can process as you like. there also a bunch of events you can hook into as well.

All this assumes you are using WPF.